# Removing Netflix From WMC8 And Adding Online Libraries?

Tags: windows-8.1, web, video-streaming, windows-media-center, netflix

I just installed Media Center on my 8.1 Pro laptop earlier and I am trying to figure a few things out. I looked for a good online guide to MC but I couldn't find one...

First question, how do I get rid of Netflix from the Movies section and why is it there in the first place? I cancelled my Netflix account just 1 week ago and I don't want to see their crap again.

[image]

When I tried to add video libraries (Tasks->Settings->Media Libraries->Video) it only had the option to add a folder:

[image]

I want to add libraries from the web, places like YouTube, Amazon, PBS, BBC, etc. These are not local folders on my machine obviously.

Can anyone tell me how do I add online libraries to Media Center for 8.1 Pro? Also, if anyone knows a good website for learning the basics of WMC please post a link!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try deleting the Folder under WMC/.../Netflix.

Make sure that Netflix is a library. It could be an application or other kind of object.

If you search long enough into options, you should be able to remove it. Most Windows Software allow an almost complete customization.

If you can't add a library, you could try moving folders into under your WMC. It should show up.

I would like to see how you resolved your problem.

Comment: I will give that a try thanks! As far as adding libraries, I don't have any videos on my local hard drive or my home network. I only watch videos online (YouTube!, Amazon Instant Video, Vimeo, etc.) The main reason why I got Media Center was I thought it would allow me to watch streaming video from the web.